# ¿Cómo ingresar como datos de entrada al modelo dos matrices simultáneamente?

Tags: python, matrices, numpy, tensorflow, keras

He creado una red neuronal sencilla que consta de una arreglo numérico en una matriz de tamaño `(size) = 192` y forma `(shape) = (4 , 48)`.  La he llamado `training_data`.

Por otro lado, tengo otra matriz de tamaño `(size) = 8` y forma (shape) = (4 , 2) y la llamé `target_data`.

Lo que realiza el modelo es que, por cada fila de 48 elementos de la matriz `training`, le corresponde una fila de 2 elementos de la matriz `target` (correspondencia 1 a 1).

El modelo funciona bien, al realizar predicción con valores de `trainig` diferentes arroja resultados coherentes.

Mi consulta es, ¿cómo hago o se puede ingresar como datos de entrada al modelo (`training_data`) no una matriz, sino dos matrices? Dejando fijo el tamaño de la matriz de salida (`target_data`) de `(4 , 2)`. Lo que deseo es separar los datos de la matrices `training de (4 , 48)` en dos matrices de `(4 , 24)`.

Adjunto parte del código, los datos y `model.fit` que es donde creo se deben especificar las dos matrices de entrada. Adjunto el GitHub también.

```
# cargamos las 4 combinaciones 
training_data = np.array([[8,6,8,6.5,7.5,5,8,6.5,9,5.5,6.5,6.5,6,7,8,104,5.5,6,8,5.5,7,6.5,8,6,8.5,4.5,5.5,6,6.5,8,6,97.5,1.4,1,3,0,1,0.3,0,6.7,0.6,0,0,1,2,0,0.3,3.9],[5.5,6,7.5,5.5,7.5,5,8,6.5,9,5.5,6.5,6.5,6,7,7.5,99.5,5,6,8,5.5,7,6.5,8.5,6.5,8.5,6,6,7,6.5,8,7,102,1.5,0,4,0,1,0,0,6.5,0.7,1,0,1,2,0,0.3,4.9],[8,7.5,8,7.5,7.5,7,8.5,7.5,9,8,8.5,7,6,7.5,7.5,115,6,6,7,5,7,6.5,7,6.5,6,5,6,4,6.5,8,7,93.5,1.4,0,4,1,2,0.3,0.3,8.9,0.7,1,0,0,4,0,0,5.7],[7,7.5,6,6.5,7.5,6.5,8.5,6.5,8,5.5,6.5,6.5,6,7.5,7.5,103.5,7.5,8,7,7.5,8,6.5,8.5,6.5,8.5,5.5,6,8,6.5,7.5,7,108.5,1.6,0,5,0,2,0,0,8.6,0.8,1,0,1,4,0.3,0.3,7.3]], "float32")

# y estos son los resultados esperados en el mismo orden
target_data = np.array([[0.666666666666667,0.333333333333333],[0,0],[1,0.333333333333333],[0.333333333333333,0.333333333333333]], "float32")

model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs=1000)
```

GitHub: https://github.com/Juan356826/Juan-Palacios/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Keras tiene "Reshape"

```
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((2,4,24))
```

Así si tienes de entrada una matriz con un shape de (4,48) utilizando el atributo Reshape, fácilmente la haces a (2,4,24), esto te sirve si quieres que tu modelo lo haga internamente

Pero si deseas separar las matrices fuera de la ejecución del modelo, puedes separarlas con el modulo reshape que tienen los arrays de numpy

```
matriz = np.random.normal(0,1,[100,]) # Crea una matriz con un shape de (100)
matriz = matriz.reshape(2,50)
```